# Is it possible to display tweets in monogame?

Tags: .net, monogame

I'm wanting to have a "news" tab in a game that would just pull and display tweets from a twitter account. Is this possible in monogame?
Should I use the Twitter API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wanting to have a "news" tab in a game that would just pull and display tweets from a twitter account. Is this possible in monogame?

It is possible in .NET as long as you have an internet connection and use the correct API. Monogame being a game framework is just another dependency of your .NET application.

> Should I use the Twitter API?

Yes, I would recommend using the Twitter REST API for the same. You can get the text data (in JSON) of the content you need.

The hard part would be to render the tweets in Monogame. You cannot render HTML or run javascript inside Monogame, so you will have to implement your own UI for "Twitter News Feed" from scratch for displaying the tweets.

Comment: For the news UI I could create my own control right?

Comment: @DanCook Yes, you need to create your own control. Fetch the text tweets using the API, draw them in your own control, and that's pretty much it.